# CircleCI - Option to continue deploying even if the exit code is 1 of one of the build steps

Tags: automation, continuous-integration, pipeline, cypress, circleci

As part of our deployment pipeline we have some E2E testing by Cypress.
In case something failed over there because a flaky test case and not because of a real bug in the project code,

We are looking for some way to re-run the job again with option to skip on the E2E testing or to keep continue the deploying even this step is failed.

Comment: To ignore the outcome of a command, you can just do `command || true`. If you want to retry it up to a certain number of times, a shell script loop would be a good thing to try.

Comment: Thanks @halfer but this is not match to my use case.

Comment: Ultimately I have taken the view that you can retry a failing step a certain number of times, and I have shown how to get a Unix success result even if a step fails, so your job does not fail and can proceed to the next step.

Comment: The job flow now is ignoring the step of the smoke testing  that meaning the step is in "hold" and if you want to run it you can click manually on this step.
The expected result we want to achieve is to run all the flow automatically but if the step of the smoke testing will be failed so we want an option to "re-run" the job again but without the step of the smoke testing for the second time. @halfer

Comment: Ah, OK. If you use the standard UI rebuild button, does CircleCI supply an env var to you that you can detect? You could do a Bash conditional check on that, if so.